# Can you use factories in a python dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

For example:

```
class Factory:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param=param
    def __call__(self, ret_val):
        print('got called')
        return ret_val*self.param

@dataclass
class Options:
    ret_val: Factory(param=3)
    verbose: bool = True
    other_flag: int = 3


o = Options(ret_val=3)
print(o.ret_val)
```

expecting

```
got called
9
```

got

```
3
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is your factory supposed to do? Why do you need it?

Comment: Well ideally I would like generic control over how the data gets processed. So given data in, I want a transformation to happen after the variable is passed in

Comment: In its core it's just a simple container for data stored as plain attributes in an object. What you store is what you get back. You need properties to make any computations.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a terribly elegant solution, but it works:

```
@dataclass
class Options:
    ret_val: int
    verbose: bool = True
    other_flag: int = 3

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.ret_val = Factory(param=3)(self.ret_val)
```